# How to get the root directory of CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, directory-structure

I've got a view with a formular (which isn't created with the form helper).
For example, I have CakePHP installed in a folder called 'myfolder1'.

So my formular starts with that line:

```
<form id="ctrlAddForm" method="post" action="/myfolder1/ctrl/add" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

But if I rename the root folder, I have to edit all formulars (2 yet).
Is there any constant or function which represents the root directory / name?

I've read about the constant [ROOT](http://book.cakephp.org/view/35/Advanced-Installation). Should I use that variable?

**Solution**

1. You can define a constant ROOT_NAME in app\webroot\index.php with `basename(ROOT)`.
2. You can use the HTML Helper function [url()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1448/url). For example in the action attribute of the form tag:

   *$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'ctrl', 'action' => 'add'));*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could try this normal ol' PHP function: [basename](http://www.php.net/basename)

```
basename(APP);
```

Since that doesn't work I actually opened up my own Cake install.  Try this:

```
basename(dirname(APP));
```

Comment: That only returns "app". But I want to use "myfolder" which is the root directory of my CakePHP installation.

Comment: Thanks the seconds code works fine!
I edited it to 
`basename(ROOT)`
so I can use that in `app\webroot\index.php` to define a constant.

Answer (score 4):

I had to get the URL of the CakePHP document root to use in Javascript, and I was able to set it up using the solution above:

```
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
         docRoot = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/'); ?>';
}
</script>
```

and that piece of code - `$this->Html->url('/')` - works perfectly in getting the root directory/URL for CakePHP.

Comment: ...and if you want this in a controller context, you can use `Router::url()` - remember to `use Cake\Routing\Router;` of course.

Answer (score 1):

This page has a list of the constants that can be used, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1141/Core-Definition-Constants

Comment: Thanks, but APP gives the full path on XAMPP: C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder1\...

But that throws an error in my browser, of course.
Then I tried APP_PATH which is empty and CAKE which only returns 'CAKE'!

Answer (score 1):

YOu can check the routes
/var/www/yourprojectname/cake/conf/paths.php

you can get all constant variable are being used through the CAKEPHP.

I hope that helps.

Regards,
Archit.

Comment: I couldn't find a variable which stores only the name of the root directory.

But see the answer of Charles.